# Is the normality of a subgroup dependent on which group is its parent?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

It is important to understand the relationship of normal subgroups to their parent. One concept that needs to be understood is whether the normality of a subgroup does not depend on which parent group it is a subgroup of. This is true for some subgroups ($\{e\}$ is always normal in any group) but is it generally speaking true for every group? The question can be phrased in symbolic form: let $G, K$ be groups and $H \leq G$ and $H \leq K$. If $H \lhd G$ then necessarily $H \lhd K$?

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed because this question is about "understanding mathematical concepts and theorems" and so is within the scope of this website.

Comment: then you should add some context.  As it stands it's a Problem Statement Question (PSQ), which the site tends to dislike.  Since it's about "understanding mathematical concepts and theorems" perhaps you could clarify which ones exactly, and motivate the question?

Comment: @postmortes Is my added context sufficient? And what is a "Problem Statement Question"? Because "Problem Statement Question" is not defined in the Help Center (I used ctrl-f) there was no way for me to know that this was against the rules.

Comment: This is a sufficiently natural question to require no motivation.

Comment: @darijgrinberg With reference to the original version of this question (and not the current version, which is much improved), I don't really believe that there is such a thing as a question that is so "natural" that it requires no motivation.  At the very least, one should give enough context to explain *why* it is a natural question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson: It suffices to read a text which often talks about "normal subgroups" without specifying the parent group to ask this question.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for supporting my point.  The admonition to read a text in which normal subgroups are discussed without mentioning a larger group indicates a context in which the question would, indeed, be natural.  A citation to such a text would help to motivate the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

$S_4$ has a Sylow-3 subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_3$, but it is not normal because the number of Sylow-3 subgroups $> 1$. And a Sylow-p subgroup is normal iff. $n_p = 1$. $S_3$ has $\mathbb{Z}_3$ as a normal Sylow-p subgroup for the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Normality *is* relative to the parent group. This is evident in the way it is defined. For a group $G$ and subgroup $N$ of $G$ we say that $N$ is normal in $G$ if for all $g \in G$ we have $N^g=N$. What brings the parent group in the definition is the "if for all $g \in G$" bit.

To give a concrete example: every group is a normal subgroup of itself, clearly. Now let $G$ be a non-abelian finite simple group and let $H$ be a proper and non-trivial subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is normal in itself, but it is not normal in $G$.